# Flutter Google Map Crashes on first open in IOS

Tags: google-maps, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a google map on the very first page of my application after the splash screen.
When I run the app for the first time and a very new build, it crashes with this error on **IOS**: **PlatformException(create_failed, can't create a view on a headless engine, null)**.

This is my google Map code and the crash happens only in IOS for the first time when the app is installed.

```
GoogleMap(
            myLocationEnabled: false,
            myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
            zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
            scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
            rotateGesturesEnabled: false,
            tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: _location,
              zoom: 12,
              /* tilt: 50.0,
                      bearing: 45.0,*/
            ),
            mapType: _currentMapType,
            markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
            onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
            onCameraIdle: _onCameraIdle,
          )
```

I am following up on this issue on GitHub : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36310
but it is not having a proper solution.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: If you're still experiencing this issue, could you share more code such as your scaffold along with supporting functions such as `_onMapCreated`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered your API key properly and in the right spot?
This needs to be registered within the **appDelegate** class before the flutter engine kicks in. **(Please note that this is a swift file)**

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("super_secret_api_key")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self); 
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps  // Add this import

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    // TODO: Add your Google Maps API key
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("google_map_api_key")
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```